# Clearing extra unnecessary data points from arrays (NAN)

Tags: arrays, r, split, nan, sapply

I'm trying to get several  means from a single sample location (15 samples - 5 means) using a dummy variable  `DUMMY_FC` I created in order to split amongst other variables. Samples were taken at many different locations at different times of years. The problem is, I get an array including every location at every time and it is displayed as `NAN`. How can I get rid of all this extra data or is there another way to get the result I'm looking for? I'm using an `sapply`, `split` function and `colMeans` function in order to get the data.

```
 s<-split(mydata, mydata[,c("LOCNAME","DUMMY_FC", "SAMPLE_YEAR")])

 sapply(s, function(x) colMeans(x[, c("LENGTH", "WEIGHT", "VALUE")],na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `drop=TRUE`

```
 s<-split(mydata, mydata[,c("LOCNAME","DUMMY_FC", "SAMPLE_YEAR")], drop=TRUE)
 sapply(s, function(x) colMeans(x[, c("LENGTH", "WEIGHT", "VALUE")],na.rm = TRUE))
 #       C.1.1990 B.1.1991 C.1.1991 A.2.1991 B.2.1991 C.2.1991 C.1.1992 B.2.1992
 #LENGTH        3        1      4.5        1        2      9.5        1        1
 #WEIGHT        4        7      5.5        4        3      6.5        5        2
 #VALUE         8        5      4.0        3        3      4.5        3        7
```

#### data

```
mydata <- structure(list(LENGTH = c(1L, 9L, 10L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 
1L), WEIGHT = c(4L, 9L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 2L), VALUE = c(3L, 
8L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 7L), LOCNAME = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"
), class = "factor"), DUMMY_FC = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L), SAMPLE_YEAR = c(1991L, 1991L, 1991L, 1990L, 1991L, 
1992L, 1991L, 1991L, 1991L, 1992L)), .Names = c("LENGTH", "WEIGHT", 
"VALUE", "LOCNAME", "DUMMY_FC", "SAMPLE_YEAR"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks that worked great! I was trying to add that to my sapply script. Also tried complete.cases and na.omit but I had no idea what i was doing. lol

Answer (score 1):

Try data.table:

```
ddt = data.table(mydata)
ddt[,list(Lmean=mean(LENGTH), Wmean=mean(WEIGHT), Vmean=mean(VALUE)),by=list(LOCNAME, DUMMY_FC, SAMPLE_YEAR)]
   LOCNAME DUMMY_FC SAMPLE_YEAR Lmean Wmean Vmean
1:       A        2        1991   1.0   4.0   3.0
2:       C        2        1991   9.5   6.5   4.5
3:       C        1        1990   3.0   4.0   8.0
4:       B        2        1991   2.0   3.0   3.0
5:       C        1        1992   1.0   5.0   3.0
6:       C        1        1991   4.5   5.5   4.0
7:       B        1        1991   1.0   7.0   5.0
8:       B        2        1992   1.0   2.0   7.0
```

---

Or you can use the inbuilt special variable `.SD` - which stands for Subset of Data that contains the intermediate data.table for each group. Since it's a data.table with the data corresponding to that group, you can simply loop over it's columns using the base function `lapply()` as you normally would, as follows:

```
ddt[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=list(LOCNAME, DUMMY_FC, SAMPLE_YEAR)]
```

You can then use `setnames()` to change the column names.